# add many straight line with given slopes and intercepts in R (output of lmer package)

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, addition

I have a mixed-effect model "logit_ri" (random intercept) from glmer function. I try to extract the fixed effect slope and the random intercept into a dataframe, and then plot it by group "Land" (German states)

```
# Extract out the fixed-effect slope 
slope <- fixef(logit_ri)['logASLr:Artl']

# Extract out the random-effect intercept for Land
Land_intercept <- ranef(logit_ri)$Land

# Create a new column for the slope
Land_intercept$slope <- slope

# Use the row names to create a county name column
Land_intercept$Land <- rownames(Land_intercept)

x <- c(seq(1:2),seq(1:2),seq(1:2),seq(1:2),seq(1:2),seq(1:2),seq(1:2),seq(1:2))
y <- c(seq(1:16))
Land_intercept <- data.frame(cbind(Land_intercept,x,y))
colnames(Land_intercept)[1]<- "intercept"
```

the dataframe looks like this:

```
Land_intercept
                          intercept     slope                   Land x  y
Baden-W¸rttemberg      -0.161346161 -2.366151      Baden-W¸rttemberg 1  1
Bayern                  0.008278875 -2.366151                 Bayern 2  2
Berlin                 -0.105067965 -2.366151                 Berlin 1  3
Brandenburg             0.507153607 -2.366151            Brandenburg 2  4
Bremen                 -0.217788246 -2.366151                 Bremen 1  5
Hamburg                -0.660789497 -2.366151                Hamburg 2  6
Hessen                 -0.217997505 -2.366151                 Hessen 1  7
Mecklenburg-Vorpommern  0.262814205 -2.366151 Mecklenburg-Vorpommern 2  8
Niedersachsen          -0.182076161 -2.366151          Niedersachsen 1  9
Nordrhein-Westfalen     0.015583050 -2.366151    Nordrhein-Westfalen 2 10
Rheinland-Pfalz        -0.239750889 -2.366151        Rheinland-Pfalz 1 11
Saarland               -0.164090824 -2.366151               Saarland 2 12
Sachsen                 0.373352938 -2.366151                Sachsen 1 13
Sachsen-Anhalt          0.443658186 -2.366151         Sachsen-Anhalt 2 14
Schleswig-Holstein     -0.098413476 -2.366151     Schleswig-Holstein 1 15
Th¸ringen               0.436479863 -2.366151              Th¸ringen 2 16
```

and plot it by ggplot2 (by "Land")

```
ggplot(data=Land_intercept,
   aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-3,1))+
  geom_abline(data=Land_intercept,aes(slope=slope,intercept=intercept,color=factor(Land)))
```

However, the intercept in my plot is not correct.
I would appreciate any helps on this.
[image]
Since I can't upload the raw data (it's huge),I may need helps to plot from the data including 16 slopes (which are all the same) and 16 intercepts for 16 German states . (as I posted above)

Better with labels also on these lines to make it more clear to read.

Or some elegant ways to plot random intercept model with slope and intercepts together would also be great.

Thank you in advance for any advices and helps.

Comment: How do you mean the intercepts are incorrect? The x-axis doesn't include x=0 so it's hard to judge for us what might be wrong with the plot.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake for setting the limit of x. I'll try it again. However, in general, do you know any ways to plot straight lines in a more elegant way? or to plot the output of glmer function. I will also appreciate it!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'a more elegant way'. The `x` and `y` columns and aesthetics seem superfluous in this case, but I wouldn't know how else to make it more elegant. I'm unfamiliar with `glmer`, so I don't know the answer to that part of your comment.

Comment: From my understanding on ggplot2, I have to anyway put something in ggplot(), that is why I set up x and y with some numbers. If it is wrong, then I would appreciate a solution for not setting x and y, and using only slopes and intercepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RE: comments

You don't need x and y aesthetics for the plot to work. For the grid to show up, you must have axis limits though. This makes sense if you think about lines parametrised by `y = a + bx` stretching to infinity.

```r
library(ggplot2)

Land_intercept <- data.frame(
  intercept = c(-0.161346161,0.008278875,
                -0.105067965,0.507153607,-0.217788246,-0.660789497,
                -0.217997505,0.262814205,-0.182076161,0.01558305,
                -0.239750889,-0.164090824,0.373352938,0.443658186,-0.098413476,
                0.436479863),
  slope = c(-2.366151,-2.366151,-2.366151,
            -2.366151,-2.366151,-2.366151,-2.366151,-2.366151,
            -2.366151,-2.366151,-2.366151,-2.366151,-2.366151,
            -2.366151,-2.366151,-2.366151),
  Land = c("Baden-W¸rttemberg","Bayern",
           "Berlin","Brandenburg","Bremen","Hamburg","Hessen",
           "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern","Niedersachsen",
           "Nordrhein-Westfalen","Rheinland-Pfalz","Saarland","Sachsen",
           "Sachsen-Anhalt","Schleswig-Holstein","Th¸ringen")
)

ggplot(Land_intercept) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = slope, intercept = intercept, colour = Land)) +
  xlim(c(-1, 1)) + ylim(c(-3,  1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for helping a beginner!  Btw, do you have any ideas to add label on these ablines or to reorder the legend by its intercepts? I have tried hard to make the information look more clear.

Comment: You can manually set the breaks in the colour scale: `scale_colour_discrete(breaks = unique(Land_intercept$Land[order(Land_intercept$intercept, decreasing = TRUE)]))`.